# How can I use the K-fold cross validation for one-class classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, one-class-classification

I train a one-class classifier by Class X. In the testing stage, I use Class X and Class Y for validation. I want to compute the F-score metric of Class Y. How can I use the K-fold cross-validation method?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to apply k-fold cross-validation in this case is like this:

- The dataset consists of all the X and Y instances. Proceed as usual to split the dataset randomly into $k$ subsets.
- When training on $k-1$ subsets, simply remove all the Y instances and train with the X instances only.
- Test normally on the remaining subset made of X and Y instances.